# When layout is complete for custom UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, autolayout

I have a custom table view cell defined in the storyboard file.

[image]

This cell contains scroll view with few pages of content and a page indicator. Scroll views, content view and cell itself all defined using auto-layout. Page1/2/3 views are bind to have same width as scroll view, and container bind to have 3 times width as scroll view. This way I unsure that content is exactly sized to show three pages of information regardless of screen size.

I have a code in the custom cell class to update page indicator when scroll view did scroll - this works fine.

I also exposed the method in the cell class to specify page from outside, and in this setter I'm doing something like that:

```
- (void)setPage:(NSInteger)page animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(page*pageWidth, 0) animated:animated];
}
```

The problem I'm facing is quite often scroll view frame and content size is not defined properly when I'm calling this setter, so the page indicator would be set, but scroll view doesn't change content offset.

Where can I catch a moment that my cell auto-layout is complete and I can guarantee that setContentOffset will work? I have try to call `setPage` from `cellForIndexPath` - that obviously doesn't work, then I tried to call it from `willDisplayCell` - same story - cell itself is already laid out properly, but scroll view still has 600px (from storyboard) and it fails.

Comment: Are you trying to display paginated content?

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be set on a bespoke implementation, so here is what might work.

Calling your `-setPage:animated:` method prior to the table view setting up its subviews, giving the cell a chance to do the same, or auto layout kicking in won't work unless you maintain some state in the cell (probably just the page number) and react to one or more of the following opportunities:

1. Waiting until the `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` method of your UITableViewController fires and then call `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to get the cell. The cell should then have a valid frame.
2. Override `-didMoveToSuperview` in your custom UITableViewCell. By the time this is called the frame should also be valid.

After either of these points you could inspect your custom cell's state (which should contain the page number that is to be displayed) and scroll to the appropriate point. It would probably make sense to refactor your method to set the state (an integer property on the cell) and have a separate private method that `-setPage:animated:` and one of the two overrides above could call to calculate the offset and do the scrolling.

---

**Suggested alternative:**

You could pull this off by embedding a UICollectionView in the cell's `contentView`. Your UIViewController that is currently implementing UITableViewDataSource could also implement UICollectionViewDataSource and provide the collection view with its cells.

Assuming that your UITableView cells are the width and height of the screen you could configure the embedded collection view to basically paginate horizontally (since UICollectionView is a subclass of UIScrollView).

When setting up the collection view use UICollectionViewFlowLayout as the layout object and configure it up like so:

```
// Ensure the collection view scrolls horizontally.
let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout();
flowLayout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal;

let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame:tableCellFrame, layout:flowLayout);

// These are actually UIScrollView properties.
collectionView.pagingEnabled = true;
collectionView.bounces = false;
```

You then place each page of content in a custom UICollectionViewCell and the collection view will paginate them for you. This has the added bonus of providing you with a paginated scrolling API for free.

Comment: Are you suggesting to put UIPageController inside the cell?

Comment: No, ditch the UITableView entirely.

Comment: That's not an option. I need to deal with this inside the cell

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you have to help me understand what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: My test project on my office machine. But setup is very simple - table view cell with 3 horizontal pages of content. And sometime I need to initialize a cell and scroll it to the second page right away.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using UITableView instead of UICollectionView?

Comment: I don't see how collection view would make things easier. I still would need to have three pages of content inside one element of collection view.

Comment: Yes, but it would be somewhat easier with a UICollectionView as the container because of the collection view layout API. I'll update my answer with my thoughts.

Comment: The cell I have scroll view in is just one of the many cells in my table view. Other cells are more standard and don't have anything. But switching to collection view would be huge headache.

Comment: I think it's really overcomplicates things. I'm just looking for a way to know when layout is complete on the cell, that's it

Comment: See my new recommendations in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for very thorough answer and time spent on this. I will post what I ended up doing, but I really appreciate your help.

Comment: this no longer works in iOS 13.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55342035/83370 works like a champ

Answer (score 33):

I ended up doing the following:

In the custom cell subclass added the `layoutSubview` implementation

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [self.contentView layoutSubviews];

     // set proper content offset
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width*self.pageControl.currentPage, 0) animated:NO];
}
```

Without me directly calling `layoutSubview` on `contentView` scroll view didn't have proper frame even after `[super layoutSubview]` was finished.

I didn't have to store current page number in internal variable, since `pageControl` already holds it and it's set when configuring original cell information.

What was interesting though - originally I added `[self.scrollView layoutSubview]` inside that method and it was working fine in iOS8, but didn't do anything good in iOS7. I had to go up one level to `contentView` to make sure it works in both 7 and 8.

Comment: This is brilliant.

Comment: ```contentView.layoutSubviews()``` is the key

Answer (score 4):

I've found out that the overriding of the UITableViewCell's layoutSubviews is not working as it should. During the first call of the layoutSubviews I get incorrect bounds of the contentView.
So I have found an alternative solution:

```swift
// implementation of the UITableViewDelegate protocol
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // the layout of the cell is ready
    }
}
```

Comment: calling cell.layoutSubviews() from inside of that async { } is the only thing that fixed my issue of applying a circle mask to an image view

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.async` is the key here

Answer (score -1):

Since layoutSubviews() is often called multiple times, it is hard to know whether or not the layout is final. Thus I've implemented an extension to UIView and use it to know which layoutSubviews() call is to be acted upon.

### Swift 4.2

```
extension UIView {

  /** A Boolean value that determines whether the view or any of its subviews need a layout update.

   This can be called from -layoutSubviews to determine if the layout of all the subviews are up-to-date.
   */
  open var needsLayout: Bool {
    get {
      return needsLayout(view: self)
    }
  }

  func needsLayout(view: UIView) -> Bool {
    var result = view.needsUpdateConstraints()
    for subview in view.subviews {
      result = result || needsLayout(view: subview)
    }
    return result
  }
}
```

Then one can simple use it in the UITableViewCell subclass:

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if !needsLayout {
      // The layout is now complete, do what you must!
    }
}
```